# Ionic/Capacitor Appium auto login

Tags: ionic-framework, appium, capacitor, appium-android

we have an app built with Ionic/Capacitor and our QA team is using Appium for tests.

They are asking if there's any way to essentially skip the login procedure (basically somehow inject JWT token that is needed for requests) and go straight to the app pages for faster testing.

I've not been able to find anything similar online, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using Mock Service Worker (msw) to mock the login request to return the JWT for you

- https://mswjs.io/

Comment: Hey @aaron-saunders , thanks for the reply!
Wouldn't that essentially be the same as actually calling login method and getting JWT token?

Comment: you just mock the endpoint so you don't actually need to have the server running